# FeatureUninstalling not called when retracting a Web Application scoped feature solution

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-feature

There is a solution that contains a Web Application scoped feature. 
I need to deactivate the feature if it is active when user is retracting a solution. So I've added an event receiver:

```
public override void FeatureUninstalling(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
```

But it's not firing(the VS debugger is attached to all w3wp and OWSTIMER processes). 
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you have problem that you are not able to debug using VS debugger or that the code written inside it is not working? (you need to first check whether the feature event-receiver is getting called. that can be done by writing a small logging code in featureuninstalling event receiver function, or any trivial code that would do something that would indicate that the event-receiver has actually been called e.g. change title of a specific site)

Comment: Any luck with figuring out what actually happened here? I'm seeing the same thing on two farms now. It was working on one of them before I did an iisreset. On my dev farm I can create a new SharePoint solution with just a FeatureUninstalling event receiver for any scope feature, and it simply never gets called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried restarting the server for few times, tried IIS reset without any luck.

The issue is fixed after following steps:
1. I've renamed a project assembly to [my_assembly_name]111.dll and deployed the solution. Feature deactivated or uninstalled has not been called. Feature installed and activated event receivers called.
2. Renemed assembly back to [my_assembly_name].dll and deployed again. Feature deactivated and uninstalled has been called. Feature installed and activated event receivers also called.

Then I've uninstalled and deployed the solution for few more times and each time all event receivers has been called withuot exception.

**There was no any problems with order of calls**. The order is same now but there is no exception anymore.

I have no idea what was the issue.

Comment: Just as a note to other readers: the issue has not been resolved as stated by @Serhiy over here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8df6c116-5458-4a83-9f36-ffd21df8d5dd/featureuninstalling-is-called-after-event-receiver-assembly-has-been-uninstalled-from-gac?forum=sharepointdevelopment